# How to close a pop-up window using PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to close a pop-up window using PHP like the javascript function `window.close()`?

Comment: `echo <script>window.close() ... ` etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php doesn't work on the client side, so... no.